# Select a random element from a list in Selenium Webdriver Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-ide

I have a code that invokes chrome driver and then goes to footlocker's website. After opening footlocker's website it finds and clicks on the Mens button. Then it goes through a list of products under men and selects one at random. The problem I am having is that it selects the same product each time. Here is my code. The method for selecting a random product is under selectRandomProduct

```
public class FootlockerExample {

WebElement next;
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

public void productOne (){

    // Open Chrome Browser
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\Working\\Workspace\\SeleniumProject\\chromedriver.exe");

    // Open Footlocker website and maximize window
    driver.get("http://www.footlocker.ca/");
    driver.manage().window().maximize();

    // Find button element 'Mens' and click
    next = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='global-nav']/ul/li[1]/a"));
    next.click();

    // Select a random product
    selectRandomProduct();

    // Print out the product name and price
    String productName = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='product_form']/div/span[2]/div/div[1]")).getText();
    String Price = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='product_form']/div/span[2]/div/div[2]")).getText(); 
    System.out.println("The 1st random product is " + productName + " and it's cost is " + Price + ".");

    // Execute new method
    productTwo();
}

public void productTwo(){

    // Go back a browser page
    driver.navigate().back();
    selectRandomProduct();

    // Print out the product name and price
    String productName = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='product_form']/div/span[2]/div/div[1]")).getText();
    String Price = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='product_form']/div/span[2]/div/div[2]")).getText(); 
    System.out.println("The 2nd random product is " + productName + " and it's cost is " + Price + ".");
}

public void selectRandomProduct(){

    // Find and click on a random product
    List<WebElement> allProducts = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='endecaResultsWrapper']/div[3]"));
    Random rand = new Random();
    int randomProduct = rand.nextInt(allProducts.size());
    allProducts.get(randomProduct).click();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    FootlockerExample obj1 = new FootlockerExample();
    obj1.productOne();
}
```

}

Comment: Could you provide a link to the footlocker website? They seem to have different page layouts for various countries. In the meantime, can you check if allProducts.size() > 1 please?

Comment: Sure the website I'm using is for Canada. http://www.footlocker.ca/. How would I go about to perform a check to see if allProducts.size() is >1? I am fairly new to Selenium.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked at the website and I found out that your xpath (`//*[@id='endecaResultsWrapper']/div[3]`) selects the whole div where there are all the images. So basically, when you click on a random element, it only finds one (the main div). If you want to click on one of the 60 products, you should try something like this: `//*[@id='endecaResultsWrapper']/div[3]//img`.

Comment: Thank you so much! That seems to have fixed the issue and is now picking different products each time.Thank you once again.